# Css rule for retina display device gets applied to ie 8

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

Hi I am using a template and there is a css rule written for retina display device. The issue is it gets applied to IE8 also. I have googled on line and the rule is rightly written, I am unable to figure out whats going wrong here. Any hekp is appreciated.

Here is the code:

```
@media (min–moz-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),
(-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3/2),
(-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),
(min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),
(min-resolution: 1.5dppx) {
/* on retina, use image that’s scaled by 2 */
.fader:before {
background: url(../mobapp/iphone@2x.png) 0 0;
}
```

which over writes the following:

```
.fader:before {
        background: url(../mobapp/iphone.png) 0 0; 
        background-size: 100%;
        left: -40px;
        width: 593px;
        height: 782px;
        top: 0px;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@media (min–moz-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),
(-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3/2),
(-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),
(min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),
(min-resolution: 1.5dppx) {
     /* on retina, use image that’s scaled by 2 */
     .fader:before {
      background: url(../mobapp/iphone@2x.png) 0 0;
}

// Pads and larger phones
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px)
{
    .fader:before {
        background: url(../mobapp/iphone.png) 0 0; 
        background-size: 100%;
        left: -40px;
        width: 593px;
        height: 782px;
        top: 0px;
    }
}

maybe
```

Comment: didnt work. I have tried different screen width also, no help. It works correctly on all browsers except IE 8.